# Struts 2.2.3 annotations based validation

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

I am using **struts 2.2.3** in web application. I want to use struts2 annotations based validations for the form data submitted from UI. The scenario is:
User fills all the form fields and click on submit button.
I have created a Person class for storing registration form data and RegistrationAction which triggers the logic for registration. RegistrationAction holds reference to person object with respected getters/setters.
Please suggest how to validate individual fields of Person class after form submission, using struts 2 annotations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it using the `fieldName` property of the `Validations` annotation. Something like the following:

`@Validations(
            requiredFields =
                    {@RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName = "person.name", message = "You must enter a value name.")}
    )`

Please refer the below link for further reference:

[Struts2 Validation-annotation](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/validation-annotation.html)

Comment: Actualy this annotation (@Validation()) is depricated since struts 2.1. Even mentioned in the link you provided.

Comment: yes i know about that :) alternate way to use JSR 303 validations and struts2 has already plugin for this [oval-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/oval-plugin.html)

Comment: Actually my problem is not which annotations to use but how to use. I can still use struts 2 annotations as only one is deprecated. So as I have mentioned in my problem statement that where to write field level annotations in Action(holding reference to Person DTO) or PersonDTO carrying form data?

Comment: @Arun The [`@Validations` annotation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validations-annotation.html) is not the same as the `@Validation` annotation. One is deprecated, `@Validations` is not.

Comment: If I want to implement annotations based validation in struts 2. Is the oval-plugin is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

On the setter method use

```
@RequiredFieldValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD, message="your message here")
```

@Validator of @Validations(...) not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Struts2 Validation Annotation.Its quite simple and Straight forward all you need is to define the `@Validation()` annotation at Class level and Apply standard or custom annotations as per your use-case.

Refer official Annotation based Validation document.

[Validation-Annotation](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/validation-annotation.html)

Comment: Actualy this annotation (@Validation()) is depricated since struts 2.1. Even mentioned in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You mention a separate `Person` class, so I am guessing that this is a model-driven Action or using a function like `setPerson` in the Action class. If you want to validate the individual fields within `Person`, you will need to use a `VisitorFieldValidator` in the relevant Action method, and then put field validations on the Person object itself.

For example in the Action

```
@VisitorFieldValidator(message = "")
public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}
```

and in `Person`

```
@RequiredFieldValidator(message = "Last name is required.")
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```